# Get File (Image) Dimesion in Laravel6.x

Tags: php, html, eloquent, laravel-6.2

In my laravel project, I have uploaded the image in database and it shows image in view file properly.
Now I want to get the image dimension, So How can I get this?
Can anyone help me plz?
This is my controller for uploading image.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        // if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        //     $image = $request->file('image');
        //     $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //     $filename = time() . "." . $extension;
        //     $image->move('public/mediaLibrary', $filename);

        // } 

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();//Getting extension
        $originalname = $image->getClientOriginalName();//Getting original name
        //this code will store image in laravel default storage folder $path = $image->storeAs('', $originalname);
        $path = $image->move('uploads/media/', $originalname);//This will store in customize folder
        $imgsizes = $path->getSize();
        $mimetype = $image->getClientMimeType();//Get MIME type

//Start Store in Database
        $picture = new mediaLibrary();
        $picture->mime = $mimetype;
        $picture->imgsize = $imgsizes;
        $picture->original_filename = $originalname;
        $picture->extension = $extension;
        $picture->filename = $path;       
        $picture->save();
//End Store
        return redirect()->route('media.index');
    }
```

This is my blade file code where i want to show

```
 <div class="card-body" >
                                <span><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Uploaded on:</span>
                                <strong><p class="text-muted" style="display: inline">
                                  {{ date('F d, Y',strtotime($data->created_at)) }} at {{ date('g : ia',strtotime($data->created_at)) }}
                                </p></strong>
                                <hr>
                                <span>File Name:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;">{{$data->original_filename}}</p></strong> 
                                <hr>
                                <span>File type:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;">{{$data->extension}}</p></strong>
                                <hr>
                                <span>Fle Size:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;"></p>{{round(($data->imgsize)/1024 )}}KB</strong>
                                {{-- <strong><p style="display: inline;"></p>{{(File::size($data->filename))/1024}} KB</strong> --}}
                                <hr>
                                <span>Dimension:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;">

                                </p></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: You look some code like that: `$data = getimagesize($filename);
 $width = $data[0];
 $height = $data[1];`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thanks for your answer. I make some minor changes in this code.

Answer (score 2):

You may use  [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)() native PHP method

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('path_to_image');
```

Or via

Intervention Image [package](http://image.intervention.io)

```
// read width of image
$width = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->width();

// read height of image
$height = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->height();
```

Comment: How to code this into my controller and show in View blade file?

Comment: list($width, $height) = getimagesize('path_to_image');
//...
//End Store
return redirect()->route('media.index', compact('width', 'height'));

<span> Dimension:</span>
<strong><p style="display: inline;">Width:  {{$width}}</p></strong>
<strong><p style="display: inline;">Height: {{$height}}</p></strong>
<hr>

Comment: why do you make 2 images ? its not performance optimized. 

`$image = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');` then you can use 
`$image->width(); $image->height();`

Comment: What if he didn't want to use intervention package ?

Comment: @NeerajTangariya If this has answered your question please may you marked it as accepted :) Thanks

Comment: I make some little changes in the code. I will put as new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Controller Image Store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();//Getting extension
        $originalname = $image->getClientOriginalName();//Getting original name
        $path = $image->move('uploads/media/', $originalname);//This will store in customize folder
        $imgsizes = $path->getSize();
        $data = getimagesize($path);
        $width = $data[0]; 
        $height = $data[1];
        $mimetype = $image->getClientMimeType();//Get MIME type

//Start Store in Database
        $picture = new mediaLibrary();
        $picture->mime = $mimetype;
        $picture->imgsize = $imgsizes;
        $picture->original_filename = $originalname;
        $picture->extension = $extension;
        $picture->width = $width;
        $picture->height = $height;
        $picture->filename = $path;     
        $picture->save();
//End Store
        return redirect()->route('media.index');
    }
```

And view the file

```
<div class="card-body" >
                                <span><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Uploaded on:</span>
                                <strong><p class="text-muted" style="display: inline">
                                  {{ date('F d, Y',strtotime($data->created_at)) }} at {{ date('g : ia',strtotime($data->created_at)) }}
                                </p></strong>
                                <hr>
                                <span>File Name:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;">{{$data->original_filename}}</p></strong> 
                                <hr>
                                <span>File type:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;">{{$data->extension}}</p></strong>
                                <hr>
                                <span>Fle Size:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;"></p>{{round(($data->imgsize)/1024 )}}KB</strong>
                                {{-- <strong><p style="display: inline;"></p>{{(File::size($data->filename))/1024}} KB</strong> --}}
                                <hr>
                                <span>Dimension:</span>
                                <strong><p style="display: inline;">
                                    {{$data->width}} <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$data->height}}
                                </p></strong>
                                <hr>
                                <span>File URL:</span>
                                <input type="text" class="mediaLib" name="image_url" value="{{url('uploads/media',$data->original_filename)}}" readonly="" style="
                                display: block; 
                                background-color: #eee;
                                padding: 0 8px;
                                line-height: 2;
                                border-radius: 4px;
                                border: 1px solid #7e8993;
                                color: #32373c;
                                border-spacing: 0;
                                width:-webkit-fill-available;">
                              </div>
```

**Note** this is the database table fields:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o506N.jpg